# Dropdown may not be the same MYSQL PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdown menu's with the same input. So "thuisteam1" can be the same as "uitteam1". But this is not what i want. I want if you have selected on "thuisteam1" a team you can not select the same team on "uitteam1".

I tried some javascript but this didn't worked for me. I hope it can be done in php. Or a javascript that does work.

Hope you people can help.

This is my code:

```
<form id="mySubmitForm" action="e2admin.php" method="post">
 <select name="thuisteam1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>

                </select>
                <input onKeyPress="return alpha(event)" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="scorethuis1" placeholder="0" />
                -
                <input onKeyPress="return alpha(event)" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="scoreuit1" placeholder="0" />
                <select name="uitteam1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>
                </select><br>
 <input style="margin-left:330px;" type="submit" class="form-control" value="Toevoegen" />

            </form>
```

Comment: You could use onchange="this.form.submit();" then check if one of the variables is set and make an if statement in your loop to not display the already selected team.

Comment: Don't know exactly what you mean can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this simple jquery can help you detect when the selected are the same:

```
$( "select" ).change(function () {
    if ($( "select[name='thuisteam1'] option:selected" ).text() == $( "select[name='uitteam1'] option:selected" ).text()) {
        $("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        alert('can not select the same');
    };

});
```

i've tryed this code and works.

here is all the example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<select name="thuisteam1" multiple="multiple">
    <option>team 1</option>
    <option>team 2</option>
    <option>team 3</option>
</select>

<select name="uitteam1" multiple="multiple">
    <option>team 1</option>
    <option>team 2</option>
    <option>team 3</option>
</select>

<script>
$( "select" )
    .change(function () {

    if ($( "select[name='thuisteam1'] option:selected" ).text() == $( "select[name='uitteam1'] option:selected" ).text()) {
        $("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        alert('same');
    };

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you calling to jQuery? put this on yout head: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: i have this code working on my local machine, in a file called stack.html, you must be doing something wrong, i need more info to help you...

Comment: I copyd it in a new files and it isn't working i don't know how haha

Comment: as it's only html and javascrip... here it is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209749/stack.html

Comment: I only have one more question: how can i add multiple dropdowns. something like:  if ($( "select[name='thuisteam1', **'thuisteam2'** ] option:selected" ).text() == $( "select[name='uitteam1', **'uitteam2'** ] option:selected" ).text()) {
        $("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        alert('same');
    };

Comment: if you have more selects, put a class in the ones you want to compare 
<select name="thuisteam1" class="group1" multiple="multiple"><select name="thuisteam1" class="group1" multiple="multiple">

Comment: But how do i add the class to the jquery

Answer (score 0):

you can send the form and validate on Server PHP Way

or you validate in Browser JS Way

in Jquery:

```
$('#<idselecttwo>').bind('change' function(){
 var valueOne = $('#<idselectone>').val();
 var valueTwo = $('#<idselecttwo>').val();
 if(valueOne == valueTwo)
 {
    alert('error');
 }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

As requested I made an example from your code. I didn't test it but that's what I ment. This code assumes that e2admin.php is the exact same file.

```
<?php

$send=$_POST['send'];
if($send==1)
{
    $team1=$_POST['thuisteam1'];
    $team2=$_POST['uitteam1'];
    if(isset($_POST['submitbutton']))
    {
        //Do your stuff
    }
}

echo '
    <form id="mySubmitForm" action="e2admin.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="send" value="1">
            <select name="thuisteam1" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                    <option value=""></option>
';
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
                        {
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                            {
                                if($team1 != $row['Team'])
                                {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
echo '
                </select>
                <select name="uitteam1" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                    <option value=""></option>
';
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
                        {
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                            {
                                if($team2 != $row['Team'])
                                {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
echo '
                </select><br>
                <input style="margin-left:330px;" type="submit" name="submitbutton" class="form-control" value="Toevoegen" />
            </form>
';

?>
```

Edit: You might want to give the submit button a name and chech isset before you proceed. This way you only proceed if they actually pushed the submit button.